# Nginx: Proxy pass meteor application as directory

Tags: nginx, meteor, proxypass

I am running a meteor application on Port 3000 and want to proxy pass it on nginx with to the adress example.com/meteor.

I tried it with the following configuration, but it fails. When I am doing it with a subdomain like meteor.example.com it is working.

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com/meteor www.example.com/meteor;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Beside this I also have a **default** configuration, which looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add /meteor location under your corrected server section

```
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name example.com www.example.com;

       location /meteor {
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
          proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       }

       #untested
       location ~ /scripts/(.*)$ {
          rewrite ^ /meteor/$1?$args permanent;
       }
    }
```

Comment: This works and redirects me to the meteor application. But now there appears another problem: When calling the page, the scripts URLs are not rewritten. They're called from the URL `example.com/scripts` instead of `example.com/meteor/scripts`.

Comment: @hideous, I don't know your app structure, but in general you have 2 options here: change links on application side or use **rewrite** on nginx side, I've added untested snippet